# Using Bootstrap's Tooltip within Polymer

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, polymer

I'm using a simple Polymer object with Bootstrap and I want to use the tooltip ([as described here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)) within the Polymer object.

Let's say this is my polymer:

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-polymer">
    <template>
        <div data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip="with a tooltip">I am a simple Polymer</div>
    </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      domready: function() {
        //$((this.shadowRoot || this).querySelector('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')).tooltip(); // not wotking
        //$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); // not wotking
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

By design, in order to get the tooltip wotking we need to execute this command:

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

But because of the shadow DOM I can't execute this command.
How can I get this code to work with the Bootstrap tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly but more giving you a "Polymer" alternative. Polymer 0.5 has a tooltip element (they look a lot like the example tooltips on the link you posted)

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-tooltip.html